# VBA to Copy Data Down from a Cell Ref in a Table to a Different Column same Row Number Down same Workbook and Autofill formula in the Adjacent Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code in a workbook which first copies data from a cell to another and then basically runs a sequel power query.

```
Public Sub ChartOfAccountsOnly()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim Lastrow As Long

Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("B1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - GAL Chart Of Accounts").Refresh

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

With Sheets("Chart Of Accounts").Range("B2")
    .Value = Now()
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
End With

End Sub
```

I am wanting to add in some code to Copy the data from a Table from A4 to the last row with Data in Column A and Paste Special the data to N4 down, then refresh the Power Query to run and thereafter Count the number of Rows in Column A from A4 down and Autofill a Formula in O4 down for the number of Rows Counted down Column A of the Table generated.

I have tried various iterations of bits of code that do simialr count and autofill on a separate workbook, and cannot get it to work, inserting

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O4:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
```

and keeps coming up with debug errors.

This is all in one workbook with one sheet.

Many thanks

Gary

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: A common error with Autofill is that the destination range does not include the source. Not sure if that is your problem, hard to know without knowing what Selection represents.

Comment: What's the error number and description?

Comment: Thank you @SJR , should I be putting the Selection statement within With statements, or should I be setting Selection as a Variable? At the moment I just inserted the Selection statement into the code above straight after the Power Query refresh statement. Excuse if I am sounding stupid, been many very late nights doing budgets :)

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome I will run again tomorrow when in office and check for error code and description, thank you.

Comment: Not sure. Can you place that line in your first block of code as I don't know how it relates?

Comment: @SJR and taller I must thank both of you for your input, it gave me food for thought, and I must apologise to both, as a Snr Finance Exec, I hate nothing more than time wasting. My apologies, I was and have been slapbang in middle of Budget prep and Month-End figures when I posted my query. With your challenges, now with a chance to breath, I have re-lokked at the code, and was silly of me posting that what I did. I have since on this past Sunday, not working for a change, managed to re-look and have resolved the issues and all working now. Thank you both for your time and patience. Gary

Comment: No problem. Feel free to post your code as an answer if you think it will help others.

Comment: Will do @SJR . Do I post it in the Q above that I asked, or do I post it here in comments?

Comment: Post it as an answer below the comment section.

Comment: Thank you @SJR will do, I see it down below.

Comment: @SJR I have posted my Answer below, thank you. Apologies taken bit of time, I have had a bereavement in the family to attend to.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve my problem to my incoherent question above, with the below code, underneath a brief explanation and screenshot of what I was trying to achieve and what I should have asked in my question. My apologies for the trouble, and thank you @SJR for food for thought in realising what I clearly wasn't explaining properly.

[image: Chart Of Accounts]

I was wanting to copy Column A to Column N Paste Special prior to refreshing the Sequel Power Query and thereafter Autofill Down the TRUE/FALSE comparison Formula in O4 down to the last Row of Data in Column A.

The Code is as follows, and welcome any suggestions on neatening up the code.

```
Public Sub ChartOfAccountsOnly()

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

     Dim Lastrow As Long

     Columns("N:N").Select
     Selection.ClearContents

     Range("A1").Select
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Selection.Copy
     Range("B1").Select
     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

     Range("A4").Select
     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
     Selection.Copy
     Range("N4").Select
     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

     ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - GAL Chart Of Accounts").Refresh
    
     Range("O4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("O4:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True

     With Sheets("Chart Of Accounts").Range("B2")
         .Value = Now()
         .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
     End With

End Sub
```